# How create a P2P web-chat without any server?

Tags: javascript, erlang, streaming, chat, real-time

is there a way to create a P2P web-chat without any server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use Flash, check out Adobe Stratus, which allows for peer to peer data and video streaming. http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/stratus/

Comment: Downvoted for flash. I know this answer is 10 years old, but it has become bad. Sorry.

Comment: it's "If you're __willing__ to use Flash" not "You need to use Flash" so i upvoted this

Answer (score 25):

Yes, but you must decide on a place to meet.

If your friend send his ip over to you, you can connect. Then you only need to tell some more people to join. After some time you will get bigger and bigger. Then, if some link on the net fail, the cloud will be broken up in two clouds(netsplit). Then everyone need to know how to get back to being "one cloud".

Some one in the cloud always have to play the server, that is done with voting. If all agreed on who is the server, then it's decided. If not agreed, shoot one down and vote again.

You have to host your own web-server to serve up the web-interface, I guess.

I have not tried this. But I think it would work.

Comment: I don't see why this answer is down voted. I agree that a login server, or rendez-vous server is a must, unless an unreliable service (from the user's point of view) is acceptable. It is also absolutely correct that without a web-server you can hardly create a web-whatever service.

Comment: It just shows how corrupt the system is. Thanks for your vote and comment.

Answer (score 3):

Malte Uble's excellent [UniversalComet](http://www.nonblocking.io/2008/12/universalcomet-making-every-client.html) article does exactly that as a proof of concept. Even works with Iphone and Android phones.